# Delete parent entity on deleting child

Tags: symfony

My problem is that my parent entity is not delete when I'm deleting child. I have *Comment* entity and two inheritance entities *ArtComment* and *PostComment*. Each one is associated with *Art* or *Post* entity. When I'm deleting *Post* entity cascade deleting automaticly deletes *PostComment* in my database but *Comment* is not deleted.

Comment:

```
/**
 * Comment
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"comment" = "Comment", "art_comment" = "ArtComment", "post_comment" = "PostComment"})
 */
class Comment 
{
}
```

PostComment:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class PostComment extends Comment {   

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="comments", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $parent;
}
```

I was trying to deal with it by creating trigger which run after deleting *ArtComment* and delete *Comment* but this solution not working.

Comment: Your example it's not so clear but what's `$parent` in `PostComment`? When you use the "Class Table Inheritance" the base entity (is `Comment`in your example) is managed internally by Doctrine because it doesn't exist physically in the DB and when you delete a `PostComment` object the "common rows" contained in the parent class are automatically deleted.

Comment: @gp_sflover in my case Comment entities exist in database. They contains all columns except one - parent. Parent is index for Post or Art entity. Should I change type of inheritance?